# Table already exists when I run pytest on Django project

Tags: django, pytest

This is a very simple issue but may take a long time resolve if you fail to look at the correct point. Especially there's not much content online to hint the source of the problem.

I have a Django project of version 3.2.5.

I created a new model: app.model. Then I ran `python manage.py makemigrations app` command.

When I ran the tests via pytest, I got the following errors:

```
E               psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "app_model" already exists
E               django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "app_model" already exists
```

However there's no such table neither on my local database nor in test database which is created from scratch.

I pushed my code on a branch to Github and build succeeded online with no problems. However my test suite complained about this existing table. I ran `python manage.py migrate app` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I realized it is a problem caused by using pytest with `--reuse-db` argument. It doesn't ask you to delete an orphan test database in this case, it reuses it.

Instead of using pytest, when I run `python manage.py test`, I got the following prompt:

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_project', or 'no' to cancel: Got an error creating the test database: database "test_project" already exists

I typed `yes`, the orphan `test_project` database was deleted & re-created from scratch and the errors disappeared.

Another solution would be using `--create-db` with `pytest command` or [adding](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#create-db-force-re-creation-of-the-test-database) this option to the `pytest.ini` file.